# Change hash without triggering a hashchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the hash to load content dynamically. To make the back button work I am capturing hash changes. However sometimes I need to change the hash without triggering the hash changed function (eg, when the page was redirected server side and I need to update the hash once the content has returned.)

The best solution I have come up with is to unbind the hashchange event, make the change and then rebind it. However, as this happens asynchronously, I am finding that it rebinds too quickly and still catches the hash change.

My solution at the moment is very poor: Rebinding in a setTimeout. Does anyone have a better idea?

```
    $(window).unbind( 'hashchange', hashChanged);
    window.location.hash  = "!" + url;
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(window).bind( 'hashchange', hashChanged);
    }, 100);
```

Edit:
Amir Raminfar's suggestion prompted me to a solution that does not require a timeout.
I added a class variable

```
_ignoreHashChange = false;
```

When I want to change the hash silently I do this:

```
_ignoreHashChange = true;
window.location.hash  = "!" + url;
```

and the hash changed event does this :

```
function hashChanged(event){
    if(_ignoreHashChange === false){
        url = window.location.hash.slice(2);
        fetchContent(url);
    }
    _ignoreHashChange = false;
}
```

Comment: You might want to check out Cowboy's BBQ library which gives you fine control over all things Back and Hashchange: http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/docs/files/jquery-ba-bbq-js.html

Comment: a nice, simple solution, you should make it an answer

Comment: The only thing left is to check that new hash is not equal the old one before setting _ignoreHashChange=true;

Comment: Where do you define the hashChanged event?

Comment: It may be good to store the original value of _ignoreHashChange and reset to that. e.g. `var _ = _ignoreHashChange; [...]; _ignoreHashChange = _`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have a function like this:

```
function updateHash(newHash){
  ...
  oldHash = newHash
}
```

then in your setTimeOut you need to do

```
function(){
  if(oldHash != currenHash){
    updateHash(currenHash);
  }
}
```

So now you can call update hash manually and it won't be triggered by the event. You can also have more parameters in updateHash to do other things.

By the way, have you looked at the jquery history plugin? http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/

Comment: It would need to be a set interval, but yes, in principle this would work. Thanks.

Comment: Yes I've looked at several plugins. They are all too bloated or buggy for my needs.

Comment: You prompted me to a better solution that does not require a time out. see the edit in my main post for details. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 29):

You could use `history.replaceState` and append the hash, to replace the current URI without triggering the `hashchange` event:

```
var newHash = 'test';

history.replaceState(null, null, document.location.pathname + '#' + newHash);
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/2zte36c7/)

Comment: `history.replaceState` also does NOT push the hashchange into history as well, but if you want that, you can use `history.pushState` ;)