# Updating the hash programmatically without triggering hashchange event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, jquery-bbq

I'm using the jQuery BBQ plugin to push states to the location.hash.

To prevent a feedback loop, I'd like to disable the hashchange listener temporarily while setting the state programmatically.

I've seen this solution:
[Change hash without triggering a hashchange event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106702/change-hash-without-triggering-a-hashchange-event)

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be perfectly robust as it sometimes triggers even though I do this:

```
updateURL(obj){
  $(window).unbind( 'hashchange');
  $.bbq.pushState(obj);
  setTimeout( function() { bindHashChange()}, 500);
}
```

**Is there now a better approach to push states programmatically? Perhaps another JS library?**

Answer (score 2):

Doing this with a timeout will not work reliably. The important part of the linked answer is setting a flag that your handler knows about. See the updated question for code.

Alternatively, bind a temporary handler to the event that is in charge of reestablishing your handler:

```
function updateState(state, handler) {
    var win = $(window);

    function temporaryHandler() {
        win.unbind('hashchange', temporaryHandler);
        win.bind('hashchange', handler);
    };

    win.unbind('hashchange', handler);
    win.bind('hashchange', temporaryHandler);

    $.bbq.pushState(state);
}
```